# How to create report based on Hierarchy in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to create report based on user that roll up to certain role for opportunity.
For example below is reporting hierarchy. All revenue is rolling to X. How can I create report so I can see revenue of X = A+B+C+D+Y+Z where A,B,C,D,Y,Z are opportunity owner and revenue rolling to X.

X > A,B,C,D and 
B > Y,Z